# Find the annihilator of $ \mathbb Z / 12 \mathbb Z $ over $ \mathbb Z \left[ \frac 1 7 \right] $

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> **Problem:** Consider $ R _ 7 = \mathbb Z \left[ \frac 1 7 \right] = \left\{ \frac a b  \big| b = 7 ^ k , k \ge 0 , a \in \mathbb Z \right\} $ and a cyclic group $ M $ of size $ 12 $. Compute $ \DeclareMathOperator \Ann {Ann} \Ann ( M ) $, where $ \Ann ( M ) = \{ r \in R _ 7 | r m = 0 \, \forall m \in M \} $.

I'm assuming that $ M $ is the group $ \mathbb Z / 12 \mathbb Z $. I know that $ \Ann ( M ) \ne \varnothing $ because $ 0 \in \Ann ( M ) $. Then my guess is that any integer multiple of $ 12 $ from $ R _ 7 $ is in $ \Ann ( M ) $ because $ r m = 0 \in M $ if $ r m \equiv 0 \pmod { 12 } $. Or should it be any $ r \in R _ 7 $ such that $ r m \equiv 0 \pmod { 12 } $?

Comment: $M\cong R_7/12 R_7$ which makes it clear that $Ann(M) = 12 R_7$